# Typescript beautify in brackets IDE

Tags: brackets

I have problem with adding new format to beautify plugin. According to this [instruction](https://github.com/brackets-beautify/brackets-beautify/wiki/External-Formatter:-TypeScript-Formatter-(tsfmt)), point .5, I Have open defaultPreferences.json in notepad, added new lines and save file. Next when I open(or refresh) brackets IDE and open defaultPreferences, there's no that new lines, also beautify dont detect typescript. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Typescript support on Brackets Extensions [Typescript extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZP65.png)
2. Install beautify [Beautify Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYFpR.png)
3. Install Typescript and Typescript-formatter globally to have them accessible across all your projects `npm install -g typescript typescript-formatter`
4. Open Brackets.json, by selecting **Debug > Open Preferences File**
5. **Note** that this will split your Brackets window, make changes in *brackets.json*, as *defaultPreferences.json* is a read-only for your reference.
6. Append the following code block to the end of your JSON object.

   "bb.beautify.beautifiers": {
       "tsfmt": {
           "command": "tsfmt"
       }
   },
   "bb.beautify.languages": {
       "css": "css",
       "ejs": "html",
       "handlebars": "html",
       "html": "html",
       "javascript": "js",
       "json": "js",
       "less": "css",
       "php": "html",
       "scss": "css",
       "svg": "html",
       "vue": "html",
       "xml": "html",
       "typescript": "tsfmt"
   }

*Had technical issues formatting the JSON, please look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83xOO.png) image for the formatted block